# .NET Remoting to WCF - Structuring solution to avoid circular dependency

Tags: wcf, projects-and-solutions, circular-dependency

I'm trying to convert an existing project that uses .NET Remoting to use WCF. The structure of the project is as follows:

- UI
- BusinessLayer

The BusinessLayer project is a class library that contains the Client-Activated Object `DistributedProcessor` which has the method `IResult Process(IJobProcessor)`. The `IJobProcessor` and `IResult` interfaces and concrete classes are all within the BusinessLayer library. The concrete classes of `IJobProcessor` in turn use many, many classes within BusinessLayer.

For .NET Remoting this situation is ideal. The distributed part is a just a Windows service that contains BusinessLayer and listens on a specific port. The client side creates the remote object using `Activator.GetObject()`.

To convert this to WCF I realized I have a circular dependency issue if I structure the project as follows:

- UI
- BusinessLayer - references WcfService
- WcfService - references BusinessLayer

The service needs a reference to BusinessLayer so that I can transfer the objects over the wire. The BusinessLayer needs a reference to the WcfService so that it can call the `IResult Process(IJobProcessor)` method on the WcfService.

Can I move the interfaces `IResult` and `IJobProcessor` out into a separate project BusinessLayerDistributed, such as:

- UI
- BusinessLayer - references BusinessLayerDistributed
- BusinessLayerDistributed
- WcfService - references BusinessLayer, BusinessLayerDistributed

My question is: If the concrete classes for all these interfaces are still in BusinessLayer, will the `IResult` and `IJobProcessor` objects be properly hydrated as their concrete class when transferred to the service? Is there any trick to doing this with WCF?

Comment: For some projects I've used this method with great success.

Answer (score 0):

Why does business layer have to call anything in service layer? Business layer should not have any knowledge about service facade layer also normal services are called from the client - never from the business layer because that doesn't make sense in service architecture.

The only exception can be duplex (bi-directional) communication but even with such architecture you will still not use circular dependency in assemblies. There are patterns to avoid that - for example business layer can have events and service layer can subscribe to them. Subscription will be done in service service layer which has reference to business layer. If you don't like events you can use Observer GoF pattern.

Another valid scenario for calling service layer from business logic is full service oriented architecture but in such case each "service" will have its own service assembly and business logic assembly you will do cross calls among them.

Comment: I don't really understand. In my case, something has to create these IJobProcessor objects. What specifically gets created, is part of the business logic.

Comment: If you have method in service layer expecting parameters the parameter is created through deserialization of client request. All other business layer classes are either instantiated in service operation itself or in service layer bootstraper.